# Change color of menu font on ActionBar

Tags: android

I wish to change the color of the menu font:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/dark_gray</item>
    <item name="android:color">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

but the menu font color is still black. What item should I add/remove?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Your previous version was good, this one is almost same like mine

Comment: I modified the answer to suit your needs. You can apply the styles directly in the parent theme too. Did that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Use this Style

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.ForceOverflow">
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/MyActionWidgetTheme</item>
    <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/MyActionWidgetTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionWidgetTheme" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:textColor">#f00</item>
</style>
```